# Which of these functions is doing what I want it to?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am taking a course and it is asking me to count how many times a word appears in a column. I figured out a way, but it seems to be counting more times than the 'official' solution.

This is the code:

```
official_solution= reviews.description.map(lambda desc: "tropical" in desc).sum()
my_way = reviews['description'].str.count('tropical').sum()
print('official solution ' + str(official_solution))
print('my way ' + str(my_way))
```

It is returning this:

```
official solution 3607
my way 3703
```

I think that my solution would be the correct one if I need to know how many times it appears in total, for example, a string can have the word 'tropical' twice. The official way would count it as one while my solution would count it as two. Am I correct or I'm confused?

I'd appreciate anyone who'd help me clear this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. To replicate the result, you can use `contains` instead of `count`.

Whenever you need to check the behavior of some function, do not hesitate to make up a tiny dataframe and run your own experiment:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'col1':['tropical tropical', 'nothing', 'tropical']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print("count", df.col1.str.count('tropical').sum())
print("contains", df.col1.str.contains('tropical').sum())

## result
## count 3
## contains 2
```

which confirms your hunch.